# Tar archive list in a bash script

Tags: bash, tar

I have a function bound to an alias for easy listing of archives.

```
function list-tar-archive {
  if [ "X$1" != 'X' ]; then
    out=tar -tf $1 | awk -F/ '{if (NF<3) print }'
    echo ${out}
  fi
}

alias list-tar='list-tar-archive'
```

Little confused why I get "no command '-tf' found" as the output when I use the alias.

```
~/workspace$ list-tar bits-and-bytes-proj.tgz
No command '-tf' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gtf' from package 'xserver-xorg-core' (main)
 Command 'tf' from package 'tf' (universe)
 Command 'tf' from package 'tf5' (universe)
 Command 'wtf' from package 'bsdgames' (universe)
-tf: command not found
```

But...

```
~/workspace$ tar -tf bits-and-bytes-proj.tgz | awk -F/ '{if (NF<3) 
print }'
bits-and-bytes-proj/
**truncated**
```

???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
out=tar -tf $1 | awk -F/ '{if (NF<3) print }'
```

runs `-tf $1` with `out` environment variable set to `tar`.

What you should actually do is:

```
list-tar() {
    if [[ $1 ]];then
        tar -tf "$1" | awk -F/ 'NF<3'
    fi
}
```

Notice the simplification to the `awk` program: the default action is `{print}`, so I just used `NF<3` as the rule that has to be true for the action to happen.  (Rules don't have to be `/regex/` patterns (which default to matching against `$0`).)  A simple grep for lines with less than two `/` characters would also do the trick.

Also notice that capturing the output into a shell variable and then echoing it is silly, unless you want to do something with it.  Your version also breaks on filenames with spaces in them.  `echo $out` word-splits `$out`, and then echo space-separates multiple arguments.  So multiple whitespace turns into a single space, and you can't tell the difference between a space in a filename and two separate files.

`[[ $1 ]]` is a better / more obvious way to write `[[ -n $1 ]]` to test for a non-empty shell variable.  [This explains](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) some of the differences between `[` and `[[`.

---

Shell functions can be run as commands, so unless you have some other reason or naming scheme, just give the function the short-name and don't bother with the alias.

Comment: so I think one correct way to do it would be "out=$(tar -tf $1 | awk -F/ '{if (NF<3) ...right?

Comment: @rpg711: I should have taken the time to write the full answer before posting.